# Sending an Email by href with '%'

Tags: html

I'm trying to send an email using href that includes % characters in the message's body.

When I'm trying to send this email using Outlook it works fine. But when I'm trying to send it using Gmail, the browser crashes.

I tried to replace the % with %25 but that crashed too.

I tried to replace the % with `&#37`; but it didn't get converted to % in the received email.

I know it may be a browser issue (Outlook doesn't open from the browser and Gmail does). How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What does browser crush mean? deform, pulverize, or force inwards by compressing forcefully.

Comment: @BillWoodger Slow your roll. I didn't mean anything by it - how do I know crush isn't a real behavior somewhere in the world? If he'd responded to my comment I would have been happy to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Having % in the message shouldn't be a problem with gmail. 
There could be a problem with your browser. Maybe you can try a different browser.

Comment: There is any way to overcome this issue, i using Chrome, and i need to add % to my message.